# Illegal instruction: 4 While running "python manage.py runserver"

Tags: python, django, macos, apple-m1

[Getting the error Illegal instruction and Python stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4juz.jpg)in macbook pro (os 12.2)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you are using the x64 version on the M1 which is ARM, as brew is reporting the issue few lines above, check how to install Python on ARM or M1